# Segment cache is not getting created in druid

Tags: druid

I am submitting a ingestion task in druid. The task is getting completed successfully and segments are created in the hdfs.

Previously with the same config, the segment cache was getting updated.

However the druid- segment cache is not getting updated with the segments of the new datasource.

I have checked and found that all the druid services are up and running.

Below is the exception, which is getting logged.

```
io.druid.query.lookup.LookupReferencesManager.start()] on object[io.druid.query.lookup.LookupReferencesManager@7336fd8f].
 INFO [main] io.druid.query.lookup.LookupReferencesManager - LookupReferencesManager is starting.
 ERROR [main] io.druid.curator.discovery.ServerDiscoverySelector - No server instance found for [druid/coordinator]
 INFO [NodeTypeWatcher[coordinator]] io.druid.curator.discovery.CuratorDruidNodeDiscoveryProvider$NodeTypeWatcher - Received INITIALIZED in node watcher for type [coordinator].
 WARN [main] io.druid.java.util.common.RetryUtils - Failed on try 1, retrying in 1,481ms.
io.druid.java.util.common.IOE: No known server
    at io.druid.discovery.DruidLeaderClient.getCurrentKnownLeader(DruidLeaderClient.java:276) ~[druid-server-0.12.2.jar:0.12.2]
    at io.druid.discovery.DruidLeaderClient.makeRequest(DruidLeaderClient.java:128) ~[druid-server-0.12.2.jar:0.12.2]
    at io.druid.query.lookup.LookupReferencesManager.fetchLookupsForTier(LookupReferencesManager.java:569) ~[druid-server-0.12.2.jar:0.12.2]
    at io.druid.query.lookup.LookupReferencesManager.tryGetLookupListFromCoordinator(LookupReferencesManager.java:420) ~[druid-server-0.12.2.jar:0.12.2]
    at io.druid.query.lookup.LookupReferencesManager.lambda$getLookupListFromCoordinator$4(LookupReferencesManager.java:398) ~[druid-server-0.12.2.jar:0.12.2]
    at io.druid.java.util.common.RetryUtils.retry(RetryUtils.java:63) [java-util-0.12.2.jar:0.12.2]
    at io.druid.java.util.common.RetryUtils.retry(RetryUtils.java:81) [java-util-0.12.2.jar:0.12.2]
    at io.druid.query.lookup.LookupReferencesManager.getLookupListFromCoordinator(LookupReferencesManager.java:388) [druid-server-0.12.2.jar:0.12.2]
    at io.druid.query.lookup.LookupReferencesManager.getLookupsList(LookupReferencesManager.java:365) [druid-server-0.12.2.jar:0.12.2]
    at io.druid.query.lookup.LookupReferencesManager.loadAllLookupsAndInitStateRef(LookupReferencesManager.java:348) [druid-server-0.12.2.jar:0.12.2]
    at io.druid.query.lookup.LookupReferencesManager.start(LookupReferencesManager.java:153) [druid-server-0.12.2.jar:0.12.2]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
    at io.druid.java.util.common.lifecycle.Lifecycle$AnnotationBasedHandler.start(Lifecycle.java:413) [java-util-0.12.2.jar:0.12.2]
    at io.druid.java.util.common.lifecycle.Lifecycle.start(Lifecycle.java:311) [java-util-0.12.2.jar:0.12.2]
    at io.druid.guice.LifecycleModule$2.start(LifecycleModule.java:134) [druid-api-0.12.2.jar:0.12.2]
    at io.druid.cli.GuiceRunnable.initLifecycle(GuiceRunnable.java:101) [druid-services-0.12.2.jar:0.12.2]
    at io.druid.cli.CliPeon.run(CliPeon.java:301) [druid-services-0.12.2.jar:0.12.2]
    at io.druid.cli.Main.main(Main.java:116) [druid-services-0.12.2.jar:0.12.2]
ERROR [main] io.druid.curator.discovery.ServerDiscoverySelector - No server instance found for [druid/coordinator]
```

Comment: This question doesn't fit Q&A format - please open an issue in https://github.com/apache/incubator-druid with the same content.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the following properties are configured or not:

```
hive.druid.broker.address.default : MyIP:8082

hive.druid.coordinator.address.default : MyIP:8081

hive.druid.http.numConnection: 20

hive.druid.http.read.timeout: PT10M

hive.druid.indexer.memory.rownum.max: 75000

hive.druid.indexer.partition.size.max: 1000000

hive.druid.indexer.segments.granularity: DAY    

hive.druid.metadata.base: druid

hive.druid.metadata.db.type: mysql

hive.druid.metadata.password: druid

hive.druid.metadata.uri: jdbc:mysql://MyIP:3306/druid

hive.druid.metadata.username: druid

hive.druid.storage.storageDirectory: /apps/hive/warehouse

hive.druid.working.directory: /tmp/druid-indexing
```